# Changing the appearance of Preference activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PreferenceActivity and theme not applying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615528/preferenceactivity-and-theme-not-applying)

I am creating preference screen having 2 panes, One for headers and one for corresponding fragment.

But I want to change layout of these preferences. For fragment I know how to do that.

But I dont know how to change layout of preference headers here. And also cannot find any relevant documentation too.

Comment: Why don't u create a normal- say ListActivity here and access Preferences from here instead of PreferenceActivity. That way u can customize the look of the activity as required.

Comment: yeah, I thought about that but Actually I am working on real Settings app of Android ICS here.

Comment: hmm then try this. It might help :http://yenliangl.blogspot.in/2011/04/customize-layout-of-preferenceactivity.html

Comment: I think that document is for old PreferenceActivity, prior to honeycomb.

Comment: yeah I too thought..coz that blogpost was made in 2009!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258323/735675

Comment: Actually I read that doc only to learn how to change layout of fragment pane, But for headers pane there is no such info available on net, Thats why I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

have you try to use styles and themes to custom your preferenceActivity?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Yeah the style is changing, but I cannot add title, footer etc.iF I try to add any layout file, the app crashes with exception: Illegalargument exception, cannot find view for fragment.